# alternate use of the CASE on table UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

This works:

```
UPDATE KEYBOARD_LEARNING a
SET a.date_completed =
CASE
  WHEN a.date_completed = '04-JUL-2012' THEN '06-JUL-2012'
    END
    WHERE a.emplid = 18
```

but this won't(below). The error I get is that datatypes don't match, and of course that makes sense because one is a DATE datatype and the other is a NUMBER.

```
UPDATE KEYBOARD_LEARNING a
SET a.date_completed =
CASE a.date_completed 
  WHEN  '04-JUL-2012' THEN '06-JUL-2012'
    END
    WHERE a.emplid = 21
```

My question: is there a workaround to make my second way work where I place the column name 'a.date_completed' in the CASE line of the SQL instead of how I got it working the first way? Am i completely off on the syntax for my second SQL?

Comment: come on, give me a break! I made it descriptive. I'm a beginner trying to get an honest answer. Why you voting me down when I looked for a similar question and didn't find what I needed? ugh

Comment: Date_completed is the DATE datatype I mention above

Comment: "one is a DATE datatype and the other is a NUMBER." and for sure '04-JUL-2012' is not a number. Hence the question

Comment: understood, I apologize if it was confusing

Comment: and thank you to whoever gave my points back from that unnecessary downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `date_completed` to String in the case statement.

Try this:

```
UPDATE KEYBOARD_LEARNING a
   SET a.date_completed =
         CASE TO_CHAR(a.date_completed, 'DD-MON-RRRR')
          WHEN  '04-JUL-2012' THEN TO_DATE('06-JUL-2012','DD-MON-RRRR')
         END
 WHERE a.emplid = 21
```

Comment: Thank you. My understanding of the CASE is what you put immediately after it is the column_name or if you don't do that right away you can alternatively put the column name in each WHEN statement. Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes you understanding is right. Its just the auto datatype conversions that are creating an issue here

Comment: You should add that `CASE` expressions have an implied `ELSE NULL` when `ELSE` is not defined.

Comment: I would rather convert the literal `'04-JUL-2012'` to a date using to_date() instead of converting the date to a character literal. But that might just be me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I usually would do that, but here was not sure what is the time component of the `date_completed` column

Answer (score 2):

You could use date literals instead:

```
UPDATE KEYBOARD_LEARNING a
SET a.date_completed =
  CASE a.date_completed 
    WHEN  DATE '2012-07-04' THEN DATE '2012-07-06'
  END
WHERE a.emplid = 21
```